# Segfault + "this project does not belong to any project target ", What does it mean?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, sfml

I'm working on this video game for school but it's not working well.

"This project does not belong to any project target" is displayed on top of the "mem_alloc" "data_des" and "data_check"  functions i wrote to malloc, destroy and check my variables.

When i run the program, it crashes and displays :

fish: Job 1, './my_runner' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

I know those two things are related but i don't know how to fix it.

I've followed a bunch of different directions i found on the internet but it didn't change a thing.

Any ideas ? Is there something i'm doing wrong ? Here is my code :

my struct : (in runner.h)

```
typedef struct data data;
struct data {
    sfBool rect;
    sfEvent event;
    sfMusic *music;
    sfTexture *texture;
    sfSprite *background;
};
```

my code :

```
#include "include/runner.h"

int main(void)
{
    window();
    return (0);
}

int window()
{
    data data;

    mem_alloc(data);
    sfVideoMode mode = { 1920, 1080, 32};
    sfRenderWindow *window = sfRenderWindow_create(mode, "No.", sfClose | sfResize, NULL);
    game_loop(window, data);
    return (0);
}

int mem_alloc(data data)
{
    data.music = malloc(1 * sizeof(sfMusic *));
    data.texture = malloc(1 * sizeof(sfTexture *));
    data.background = malloc(1 * sizeof(sfSprite *));

    if(data_check(data) != 0)
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    fill_struct(data);
    return (0);
}

int data_check(data data)
{
    if (data.music == NULL)
        return (1);
    if (data.window == NULL)
        return (2);
    if (data.texture == NULL)
        return (3);
    if (data.background == NULL)
        return (4);
    else
        return (0);
}

int fill_struct(data data)
{
    data.rect = sfFalse;
    data.background = sfSprite_create();
    data.music = sfMusic_createFromFile("src/ogg/runner.ogg");
    data.texture = sfTexture_createFromFile("src/png/StarryNight.png", NULL);

    if (data_check(data) != 0)
        return (1);
    return (0);
}

int game_loop(sfRenderWindow *window, data data)
{
    sfSprite_setTexture(data.background, data.texture, data.rect);
    while (sfRenderWindow_isOpen(window)) {
        sfRenderWindow_clear(window, sfBlack);
        sfRenderWindow_drawSprite(window, data.background, NULL);
        sfRenderWindow_display(window);
        while (sfRenderWindow_pollEvent(window, &data.event)) {
            if ((data.event.type == sfEvtKeyPressed && data.event.key.code == sfKeyEscape) || data.event.type == sfEvtClosed) {
                sfRenderWindow_close(window);
                data_des(window, data);
            }
        }
    }
    return (0);
}

int data_des(sfRenderWindow *window, data data)
{
    if (sfRenderWindow_isOpen(window)) {
        sfMusic_destroy(data.music);
        sfRenderWindow_destroy(window);
        sfTexture_destroy(data.texture);
        sfSprite_destroy(data.background);
        return (0);
    }
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: After allocating memory for music, texture and background, you are overwriting the returned pointers by other pointers returned by the funcitons `...create...()`. So you cannot `free()` the allocated memory, and you don't do it. However, this does not lead to a crash. -- Would you mind to [edit] your question to show us a [mre], please? Presumably the problem is in some code you don't show us currently.

Comment: this is missing the typedef's for the fields in the struct definition
this is missing the needed prototypes for the ''forward referenced' functions

Comment: regarding: `if(data_check(data) != 0)
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    fill_struct(data);
    return (0);`  these return values are never checked in the calling function

Comment: regarding: `int fill_struct(data data)
{
    data.rect = sfFalse;` and the following statements:  if you want to change the values in the passed in struct then you have to pass a pointer to that struct and reference the fields via: `data->rect = sfFalse;`

Comment: it is a very bad idea to name the data object (window) and the function name (window) the same